# Any way to access directory nodes?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In Jekyll 2, suppose I have a collection named `mycol` and that it has a structure like this in the filesystem:

```
_mycol/
  00-intro.md
  01-preface/
    00-intro.md
    01-something.md
    02-subsection/
      00-intro.md
    03-hello.md
  02-section/
    00-intro.md
```

Is there any way to do have inner loops and detect if the current item is a directory or actual data?

Here's an example of what I would like :

```
{% for d in site.mycol %}
    {% if d.content %}
        {{ d.content }}
    {% else %}
        {% for v in d %}
            {% if v.content %}
                {{ v.content }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there any know way or hack to achieve this?